# Pressing Home Key triggers an error

Tags: android

I have created an image editing app..it consists of two activities, the main activity leads to next activity. Everything's working fine. The problem is when i press HOME key during second activity it jumps to the home screen now when i again run the application it generates an error to force close. This ain't happening when doing the same during first activity. I'm not able to find the exact problem..
Is there any way that if user presses HOME key i can kill that activity?

below is the code of surfaceview i'm using...it's also using a thread...i think dat's where dis prblem is arising...can u pls check dis out

```
public DrawingSurface(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    getHolder().addCallback(this);

    commandManager = new CommandManager();
    da=new DrawingActivity();
    thread = new DrawThread(getHolder());
}


class DrawThread extends  Thread{
    private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;


    public DrawThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder){
        mSurfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;

    }

    public void setRunning(boolean run) {
        _run = run;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        Canvas canvas = null;
        b=da.getpic();

        while (_run){
            try{
                canvas = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                if(mBitmap == null){
                    mBitmap =  Bitmap.createBitmap (1, 1, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);;
                }
                final Canvas c = new Canvas (mBitmap);


                c.drawBitmap(b, 0, 0, null);
                commandManager.executeAll(c);

                canvas.drawBitmap (mBitmap, 0,  0,null); //first block

            } finally {
                mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }

    }


}


public void addDrawingPath (DrawingPath drawingPath){
    commandManager.addCommand(drawingPath);
}

public boolean hasMoreRedo(){
    return commandManager.hasMoreRedo();
}

public void redo(){
    commandManager.redo();
}

public void undo(){
    commandManager.undo();
}

public boolean hasMoreUndo(){
    return commandManager.hasMoreRedo();
}
public Bitmap getBitmap(){

    return mBitmap;
}


public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,  int height) {

    mBitmap =  Bitmap.createBitmap (width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    thread.setRunning(true);
    thread.start();

}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    boolean retry = true;
    thread.setRunning(false);
    while (retry) {
        try {
            thread.join();
            retry = false;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This could have so many specific causes so you should post the exception which is thrown and some code. From that discription it's not possible to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your activity to kill the application on HOME key press

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME) {
        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
    }
    return true;
}
```

Oddly enough, even the BACK button doesn't quit it.

Comment: thnx for the answer but it's not working...is it something to do with surface view and threading..??

Answer (score 0):

Let us know what exception do you get, when you bring your application to foreground.

This happens, when you have not reinitialised some objects or variables.

You need to store the values of your variables, that go null, in shared preferences, in onPause() method. You can fetch these values from SharedPrefs, and assign them back to the variables or recreate the objects that go null in onResume() method.

When Android runs on low memory, it kills some activities, or cleans some variables and objects, when the application goes to background. Thats why you need to take care of it, in onPause() and onResume() nmethods...

Hope it helps...

Answer (score -3):

Try this for home key press

```
    @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setClass(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(i);

        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: How HOME key is related to KEYCODE_BACK ! I thought that is for BACK btn !

Comment: Pressing HOME doesn't trigger onKeyDown